# Reset Md-Slide-Toggle if user cancels dialog

Tags: angular, toggle

**Situation**

The user can click an `<md-slide-toggle>`. Whenever the user slides the toggle from `true` to `false`, a dialog should appear asking the user to confirm their choice. If the user clicks "Cancel", as opposed to "Continue", the toggle should slide back to `true` (alternatively, I'd be interested in a solution where the toggle doesn't slide before the user is confronted with the dialog).

**Problem**

When the user chooses to cancel their decision, the toggle fails to update alongside the model it's bound to.

**TS**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'toggle-parent',
    templateUrl: 'toggle-parent.component.html'
})

export class ToggleParentComponent {
    @Input() isChecked: boolean;

    onToggle(): void {
        WL.SimpleDialog.show('title', 'text', 
                [
                    {text: 'Cancel', handler: () => this.toggleReset()},
                    {text: 'Continue'}
                ];)
    }

    toggleReset(): void {
        this.isChecked = !this.isChecked;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<md-slide-toggle 
    [(ngModel)]="isChecked" 
    (change)="onToggle()">
</md-slide-toggle>
```

**Question**
Why won't the slider revert back to it's previous state when I invert the value of `isChecked`? Shouldn't it?

If this isn't the best way to do this, what would be a better approach?

**Edit**: Added code for dialog upon request

**Edit 2**: I think the issue I was having was with managing 3 layers of components. I didn't upload all of my code, but in the actual implementation, I have a component to manage a page, which uses a container component to hold the slide-toggle and a label, which uses the md-slide-toggle. I was trying to manage 2-way binding through 3 layers:

PageComponent -> ContainerComponent -> MdSlideToggleComponent

When I took out the middle layer, the two-way binding worked. However, with 3 layers, whenever I would change isChecked on PageComponent, it would update the change on ContainerComponent only and it would trickle down no further. So my changes weren't making it all the way down. It was likely human error that produced the overall problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks good to me. I don't see reason for `toggle-slider`not to revert back. But, if you want to get user's confirmation before toggling the slider, you can do it by adding a `click` event: `(click)="onToggle(); false"`

Then add logic to handle user response from the dialog. My example is using `md-dialog`

```
openDialog() {
      let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogResultExampleDialog);
      dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        console.log(result);
        if(result === "continue"){
          this.toggleReset();
        }
      });
    }
```

Plnkr [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/8oehVZ?p=preview)

Comment: What's the purpose of the false next to onToggle()?

Comment: To stop the click event from propagating beyond the initial element

Answer (score 0):

Another solution found was to try this:

```
<md-slide-toggle 
    [(ngModel)]="isChecked 
    (change)="slider._checked=onToggle()" 
    #slider>
</md-slide-toggle>
```

What's happening above is I'm using a template reference variable to refer to the slide-toggle, then altering it's `checked` property by assigning a boolean to it, returned by function `onToggle`, which will launch a dialog to determine if the return value will be `true` or `false`.